# Можно ли выложить приложение на основе чужого сайта

Tags: android, google-play, android-webview

Хочу выложить приложение в play market, я делал его на основе определенного сайта, просто применив для него webview и разделил на фрагменты. Вопрос, может ли владелец сайта пожаловаться на моё приложение и какое последствие это может иметь?

Comment: В инете плагиат на плагиате. Но если все повторяется прям в точности включая контент, то да. Это нарушение авторский прав и интеллектуальной собственности. Что вам за это будет зависит от того какой доход вы от этого получили. Могут и в клетку посадить, если не возместить ущерб владельцу

Comment: Вероятнее всего вы даже ревью не пройдете. Ревьювер найдет чужой контент и будет от вас хотеть разрешение от владельца. Google Play уже давно не тот, что все подряд разрешалось заливать.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/news/t/665742/

Comment: гугл в целом не любит приложение, которые построены только на webview. так что вряд ли.